# Position dodge not working in time series

Tags: r, ggplot2, position-dodge

I want to dodge the points and error bars on this time series, but I keep getting stacked points/error bars

```
AcrossSites<-structure(list(ExpectedPA = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("0", "1", "5", "20", "50"), class = "factor"), 
    Date = structure(c(1649721600, 1653609600, 1657497600, 1660262400, 
    1662508800, 1649721600, 1653609600, 1657497600, 1660262400, 
    1662508800, 1649721600, 1653609600, 1657497600, 1660262400, 
    1662508800, 1649721600, 1653609600, 1657497600, 1660262400, 
    1662508800, 1649721600, 1653609600, 1657497600, 1660262400, 
    1662508800), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    )), avg = c(79, 55.5, 63.7916666666667, 53.2916666666667, 
    64.5416666666667, 79.7916666666667, 53.2916666666667, 52.9166666666667, 
    43.9166666666667, 48.5, 75.1666666666667, 56.2916666666667, 
    63.8333333333333, 53.7916666666667, 65.5416666666667, 74.9583333333333, 
    61.25, 55.375, 43.2083333333333, 47.5416666666667, 80.9166666666667, 
    63.125, 57, 51.2916666666667, 49.9583333333333), SE = c(2.46717581897585, 
    2.05362881367296, 3.5914447290117, 3.92939459818081, 6.08632917100101, 
    2.70933649203142, 2.69895253881266, 4.06688494306104, 4.94422392712404, 
    6.65097791654557, 2.56415273083589, 2.67535665146918, 3.56394315628856, 
    4.71044905651358, 7.02814712802315, 2.26302923721776, 1.89129393633649, 
    4.1230232417698, 4.1702792310269, 5.23746923019105, 2.20006313040735, 
    1.69217348015992, 3.87765804114519, 4.22230068418071, 5.85249827946247
    )), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -25L), groups = structure(list(ExpectedPA = structure(1:5, .Label = c("0", 
"1", "5", "20", "50"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
    1:5, 6:10, 11:15, 16:20, 21:25), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Here's my data frame, and I want to graph "ExpectedPA" changing over time

```
ggplot(AcrossSites, aes(x=Date, y=avg, ymin=avg-SE, ymax=avg+SE, color=ExpectedPA))+
  geom_line(size=1, position=position_dodge(width=10))+
  geom_point(position =position_dodge(width=10), size=2)+
  geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(width=10), width=10, size=0.6)+
  ylab("Total Stems")+
  ggtitle("Total Stems Across Sites")+
  xlab("")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = c(.8, .8), text = element_text(color="black", size = 12))
```

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to convert your datetimes to dates. Not sure whether that is an option for you but at least from your example data I don't see any reason to work with date times.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(AcrossSites, aes(x = as.Date(Date), y = avg, ymin = avg - SE, ymax = avg + SE, color = ExpectedPA)) +
  geom_line(size = 1, position = position_dodge(width = 10)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 10), size = 2) +
  geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge(width = 10), width = .1, size = 0.6) +
  ylab("Total Stems") +
  ggtitle("Total Stems Across Sites") +
  xlab("") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = c(.8, .8), text = element_text(color = "black", size = 12))
```

[image]

**UPDATE** I had another look. Dodging works for date times too. But to make it visible we have to increase the width even further, e.g. in the code below I use `1e6`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(AcrossSites, aes(x = Date, y = avg, ymin = avg - SE, ymax = avg + SE, color = ExpectedPA)) +
  geom_line(size = 1, position = position_dodge(width = 1e6)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 1e6), size = 2) +
  geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge(width = 1e6), width = .1, size = 0.6) +
  ylab("Total Stems") +
  ggtitle("Total Stems Across Sites") +
  xlab("") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = c(.8, .8), text = element_text(color = "black", size = 12))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I take it you can't dodge a datetime?

Comment: Hi Hallie. I just had another look. And actually the dodging is already present in your original plot. But it's hardly or not visible. To make it visible increase the width for the dodging. See my update.